# How do i get the code to read each region from the list

Tags: python

```
        region=['North','South','East','West']
        PSI=[]
        print(f"Enter PSI for {region[0]}: ",end='')
        user_input=input()
        PSI.append(user_input)
```

How to get get the code to print each region without typing more than 1 print statement ?

Comment: Do you mean to write a loop?!

Comment: Use a loop! `for r in region: print and input in the loop...`

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write a `for` loop, which will iterate over the `region` list.

```
region=['North','South','East','West']

PSI=[]

for i in region:
    print(f"Enter PSI for {region[i]}: ")

user_input=input()
PSI.append(user_input)
```

Hope this helps!